# Apache "alias" stopped working

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008-r2, mod-alias

I have a web server running since 2014 on Windows Server 2008R2 with Apache 2.2.25, PHP and stuff. It has some `Alias` directives inside its `<VirtualHost>` config entry, which seemingly had stopped working some time ago. Nothing and really nothing has changed in the past 3 years in that config, I've even recovered a backup dated 3Y back, and still aliases are not working. I have tried reinstalling Apache, no dice. The problem is that the site works as a whole, so it's not Apache-related error. I was able to work around the problem by plain merging the folders so that HTTP path matches the FS path, but I'd still like to know how to restore the functionality to mod_alias.

An excerpt from config is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost www.company.com:80>
DocumentRoot "d:/webroot/company/public_html"
ServerName www.company.com
Alias /outsourcing "D:/webroot/outsourcing"
Alias /rent "D:/webroot/rent"
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
<Directory "D:/webroot/rent">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory "D:/webroot/outsourcing">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all      
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please share your related configuration.

Comment: @EsaJokinen Here you are.